# can't play mp3 file in python, its first day of learning code

Tags: python

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('C:\\Users\\Ahsan Ali\\Downloads\\shower.mp3')
```

ERROR : (but the path is correct .... but still error)

```
PS E:\python> & "C:/Users/Ahsan Ali/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" e:/python/01_hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python\01_hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    playsound('C:\\Users\\Ahsan Ali\\Downloads\\shower.mp3')
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 31, in winCommand   
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 275 for command:
        open "C:\Users\Ahsan Ali\Downloads\shower.mp3" alias playsound_0.8852709796417568
    Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure the path and filename are correct.
```

Comment: Use raw strings for your Windows paths containing backslashes: `playsound(r'C:\Users\Ahsan Ali\Downloads\shower.mp3')` - note the `r` before the opening quote.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille wrong answer to question, but using 'r' prefix is very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Someone in comments said you should use 'r' prefix but double backslahes provides escaping too, you don't have to use 'r' prefix. Error says it can't find the file.

```
Error 275 for command:
        open "C:\Users\Ahsan Ali\Downloads\shower.mp3" alias playsound_0.8852709796417568
    Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure the path and filename are correct.
```

double check your songs name or the path...